# Am I using setTimeout in an inefficient manner?

Tags: javascript, angular, settimeout

I have an angular app and I want to implement a 'Time Ago' feature. If I render some crazy number of 'questions', would this be a bad idea?

If you can imagine a facebook post that says 'posted about a minute ago...', that's what I'm shooting for.

The assumption is that the user never refreshed the page and the questions are appended to the angular mdoel from a signlar hub

```
export interface IQuestion {
  timeAgo: string;
}

export class Question implements IQuestion {
  public timeAgo: string;
  constructor(question: IQuestion) {
    this.timeAgoTicker();
  }
  timeAgoTicker(): void {
    this.timeAgo = 'just now';
    setTimeout( () => this.timeAgo = 'about a minute ago', 10000);
    setTimeout( () => this.timeAgo = 'a couple of minutes ago', 20000);
    setTimeout( () => this.timeAgo = '5 minutes ago', 50000);
    // etc...
  }
}
```

Comment: Hmmm, I would prefer a timeout that looks at all questions and updates them on the page using say a switch statement. This adds load on a page (although not a big deal)

Comment: I should mention that questions are being delivered in real time via SignalR. The management of 'when to start the timer' is assumed to be accurate.

Comment: It kind of gets away from separating our model from our presentation. make sense? What about multi lingual etc. I think the idea is cool. But I would still with a centralized refresh of the presentation layer that looks at the model collection.

Comment: That's what led to the question. I had a dumb idea that seemed somewhat logical. I just wasn't sure if a bunch of setTimeouts would be a bad idea. Do you have an example?

Comment: I am happy to write an example that might refresh on a list of objects. I see you are using typescript. You happy with vanilla JS? btw. The idea is definitely a fun one.

Comment: But, keep in mind, this is in an angular app. These are basically html snippets in an `ngFor` with a model bound to them.

Comment: instead of using `setTimeout`, which is intended for asynchronicity, you can create a  new date in the constructor (`this.date = new Date()`) and then calculate `Date.now() - this.date.valueOf()` for the difference

Comment: Yea, but I need it to update in real time. It's a SPA app so refreshing the page to establish a new `timeAgo` would defat the purpose. I need something that will always update the `timeAgo` property with the correct time. Event when the user is doing nothing on the page. Trying to leverage the 2 way databinding in angular

Comment: Regardless of framework. I am assume these `items` are being added to the `DOM` periodically. So maybe ensure the element has a `data-question-date` and a common `class`. We can have a single timeout. That updates them all.

Comment: If you take a look at how StackExchange does this, they do start an 60000ms interval which looks for all `$('span.relativetime, span.relativetime-clean')` and then update their textContent based on the currentTime. (in [full.js](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/full.en.js?v=1e5901a4df24))

Comment: @Bibbderty I see what you're saying. I guess the question then becomes a matter of if it's more efficient to have a single timeout that pool a list of an unknown amount of items or to have each one of those items update themselves based on their model

Comment: @kaiido that's super useful. Where do you see this?

Comment: If you tidy full.js you'll find there is a factory `StackExchange.realtime` which does this. Search for `relativetime` to find function `L` (will probably change in the future), then search where this function is being called in the same scope (it is in the function `r` of current version), an there you'll see it's called inside a function itself called every 60000ms.

Comment: ...Interesting approach. It's aligns with @bibberty was suggesting. I frown upon jQuery, but that's not needed to achieve the same solution as you mentioned. I'm still curious if pooling the list in the dom is more efficent than just having models update themselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what the performance effect of having many setTimeout calls is, but I would rather set `timeAgo` to be a date object, and then check the difference between `now` and that date object whenever updating the UI:

```
export interface IQuestion {
  createdAt: Date;
}

export class Question implements IQuestion {
  public createdAt: Date;
  constructor(question: IQuestion) {
    this.createdAt = new Date();
  }

  getAge(): String {
    return (new Date() - this.createdAt).toSomeStringAccordingToAge()
  }
}
```

I don't know if the syntax is correct since I don't use Typescript. For example, as one of the comments mentioned below states it would be better to use an accessor (`getter`).

Comment: Then somewhere else you could have a single `setTimeout` method that regularly updates the UI according to the result. Or if it's single direction state propagation, then the `getAge()` method should update that

Comment: I guess implementing a feature on the component that is rendering the answers to calculate the time ago would be another alternative. I guess my concern is the amount. If it's just a couple questions, it doesn't mater. But if I end up with 1 million questions, it would obviously not pan out. In that outrageous example, would you rather run a setTimeout to re-evaluate the list or have each individual record update themselves with `setTimeout`?

Comment: I have no idea what even `const x = 'hi'` would do if run a million times. Rather get it working according to your best current knowledge and then fix performance bottlenecks as they come up. This will save you time in the long run.

Comment: Otherwise you will find that your 'optimized' solutions that took time to figure out aren't actually optimized - so you have to change them anyway, and they tend to make code more complex

Comment: Alternatively.... research it. Create an example .html file with `<script>` tags. In ti put a loop `for (let i = 0; i < 1000000; i ++) {do something with setTimeout}` and see what the performance is like. I think Chrome dev tools probably has performance metrics

Comment: .... also. in event that you have a million questions I think a bigger problem would be loading them onto the client over the network

Comment: I like this but with one suggestion. Use a getter instead of a method `get age(): String { return ... }`

Answer (score -3):

Ok, `newQuestion` and the first `setTimeout` are only boilerplate code to get something working to test. Please ignore. The second setInteval is where we look at our `data` attribute. This attribute is HTML standard compliant. and can be accessed through `[HTMLElement].dataset`. We test our post time against current. In a single method.

```js
const newQuestion = () => {
  let target = document.querySelector('.questions');
  let question = document.createElement('div');
  question.className = 'question';
  question.setAttribute('data-question-date', Date.now());
  question.innerHTML = '<span>Test Question - <span><span class="age">Just Now</span>';
  target.appendChild(question);
  
};

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  setInterval(() => {
    newQuestion();
  }, 5000); 
  
  setInterval(() => {
    let questions = document.querySelectorAll('.question');
    questions.forEach(q => {
      let dateofQ = q.dataset.questionDate;
      let age = Math.floor((Date.now() - dateofQ)/1000);
      console.log(`age: ${age}`); 
      let ageElement = q.querySelector('.age');
      //do just 20 secs, so we don't have to wait.
      if(age < 20) {
        ageElement.innerHTML = 'Just now';
      } else if (age < 300) {
        ageElement.innerHTML = 'Less than 5 minutes ago.';
      } else {
        ageElement.innerHTML = 'More than 5 minutes ago.';
      }
    });
    
  }, 1000);
});
```

```html
<div class="questions">


</div>
```

Comment: I didn't vote on this, but code-only answers are frequently voted down. It's much more helpful if you can add some explanation.

Comment: The question wasn't 'how to do it'. It was 'is this the most efficient way to do it'. Your answer not only goes against the angular framework but is also a regurgitation of how to do the same thing that's already been done in a vanilla js way --- which was not asked.

Comment: But you asked if it was 'efficient'. The vanilla is only there to scaffold the demo.